# create entitymanager using jdbc connection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a requirement where I need to create a jpa entity manager instance using plain jdbc connection. more precisely I have a jdbc connection and from that I want to create an entitymanager instance.

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html)?

Comment: Your problem would be a whole lot simpler and actually possible to solve if you'd have an EntityManager with a connection and you want to reuse that connection for other purposes. I can imagine you want this "shared datasource" because you want several isolated pieces of logic to share the same transaction? If so then JTA with distributed transactions may be more in the direction of a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is java programming interface specification that describes the management of relational data in applications using Java Platform, Standard Edition and Java Platform, Enterprise Edition. So you need some implementation api's like hibernate, Spring repo etc to make your application JPA enabled.

Comment: i am using eclipselink implementation. is there a way where we can wrap connection to entitymanager??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use connection parameters or JNDI Datasource name in the definition of your persistence unit.

As for using your own JDBC connection, the EntityManagerFactory implementation would need to know how to do this, and I doubt any implementations (hibernate or others) are meant to work the way your want it.

Maybe implement a datasource which returns the connection any way you like.